# Sum of angles of triangles in negative curvature manifolds of high dimension

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature

Let $(M,g)$ Riemannian manifold of dimension $\geq3$ with sectional curvatures $\leq0$ and let $p\in M$ such that some sectional curvatures are $<0$ at $p$. Can we find an arbitrarily small geodesic triangle $pqr$, with angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ at $p$, such that the sum of its angles is $<\pi$?

Motivation: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/q/447199/172802) MO question.

Comment: What comparison theorems do you know?

Comment: Basically none, I am studying the book "Introduction to Riemannian manifolds", by Lee, and I just started with Jacobi fields. The chapter after that is called "comparison theory" so it probably contains results like the ones you refer to. I glanced over it but found no results comparing lengths, maybe it's me not understanding the notation though. I have also seen the CAT inequalities for metric spaces (comparison triangles and all that), although I am not sure how they could be applied here.

Comment: Check the book by Bridson and Haefliger instead.

Comment: New Edition (2018) of Lee's Book has a "comparison theorems " chapter.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks, I will take a look. What concrete result from the book can solve my question, or what chapters should I search in? It doesn't seem obvious from the table of contents of the book.

Comment: In Bridson and Haefliger, read Section II.1 and the appendix to it. This will answer all your questions. Maybe it is also in the new edition of Lee's book, I would have to check.